# How to dispose of dynamically loaded usercontrols/viewmodels when parent window is closed

Tags: wpf, window, dispose

We have a main window that launches a child window. That child window dynamically loads custom usercontrols. In the contructor of these usercontrols, I pass a master object which, from this master object, a usercontrol specific viewmodel is generated and assigned as its datacontext.

All of this is working quite well. However, I jst discovered that when I close the child window at least some of my custom usercontrols are still active. How am I supposed to clean up my controls/viewmodels? Nothing seems to get called until the main window is closed. No destructor, no Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted, no dispose is available, no closing event, nothing I can find.

Anyone know what is supposed to be done to properly clean up after the window is closed?

Comment: How do you know your controls are still active?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to think precisely about what is responsible for creating your views and your viewmodels, and what is responsible for determining whether or not something can close or not, etc.

It is usually a good idea for whatever that created something to destroy it. Therefore, if your child window is creating custom user controls it perhaps should be responsible for removing them. However, I believe if none of your objects has a reference (or strong event subscription) it should be eventually garbage collected. You could implement a finalizer/destructor and output a Debug.String to the output window to see when this might eventually happen. A good memory profiler could also be a good idea. However, it is also likely that you need more precise control of telling your ViewModel when it has been closed.

It's hard to say exactly what should happen in your scenario because it really depends on your exact and specific setup. Let me describe to you a scenario I had in my application. I had several views that were being displayed in tab pages. The tab pages had an X button to close the tab, and my View contained a hosted Windows Forms control that needed to have .Dispose() called to clean up resources as well as it needed to be informed of when to unsubscribe from composite commands in the file menu system. So, initially, I had a problem... how does my ViewModel unsubscribe from commands when the tab pages remove's the view? How does the View which is contained in a WPF control know when it has been removed? here's what I came up with

1. The tab page itself should not be telling my program if a view can or can not be closed
2. I needed the ability to cancel the closing event in case of program logic (File saved? Yes/no/cancel)
3. I needed the ability to detect when it was closed so I could cleanup/unregister at that exact moment

My solution was to implement an interface in my viewmodel called IRemovable which exposed a Removable boolean and a Remove() method which returns a boolean (was removed or not). My tab control only displayed the X button if Removable was true, Tab Control's Closing fired the Remove() of the IRemovable ViewModel and if it returned false it set the event args Canceled property to true if the ViewModel's Remove returned false.

Therefore, the remove of the view model could prompt the user for confirmation, unregister from commands, etc. The view could handle Closed event and call Dispose on any Windows Forms components etc. (of course I had to check if my View.DataContext is IRemovable).

Anyway, I know this isn't an exact answer but hopefully it helps you come up with some thoughts on how to solve your own problem